# Use pgm_read_word in sprintf_P

Tags: c++, arduino

for my hobby arduino project I use PROGMEM to save dynamic memory space.

I have build const chars and save them into an array table:

```
const char KEY[] PROGMEM= "z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5.....";
.
.
const char * const MARRAY[7] PROGMEM =
{APN,URL,API,KEY,ACTION,TIMEZONE,IDENT,};
```

Now I want to use the strings inside a *snpritf_P*, but this code wont work as expected:

```
char * ptr = (char*) pgm_read_word(&MARRAY[0]);
snprintf_P(conv, sizeof(conv), PSTR("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"%s\""), ptr);
```

If I create a string and copy the char into the string it will work:

```
char * ptr = (char*) pgm_read_word(&MARRAY[0]);
String buffer [80];
strcpy_P (buffer, ptr);
snprintf_P(conv, sizeof(conv), PSTR("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"%s\""), buffer);
```

I really do not understand why the first code not works, *snprintf* is normally expecting a *char* as far as I know?

Any tips/help would be great, I already read the [Arduino PROGMEM Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM) 
but still wont understand it.

Cheers From Austria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in using `snprintf_P` to allow the format string to be read from PROGMEM.  However, if the format string contains `%s`, then the corresponding argument must be in RAM, not FLASH memory.

To specify that the string argument is in FLASH memory, you must use `%S` in the format string, with a capital S:

```
snprintf_P(conv, sizeof(conv), PSTR("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"%S\""), ptr);
```

This is a unique feature of the AVR libc library, documented [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1).

Comment: Awesome thank you, works like a charm and it saves me a buffer variable. Could save 10%  of my dynamic memory. Still need to save more but it's a good start. :) Thanks again!